# Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Http.WebHost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm running my application on an IIS server, but now I want to do some debugging with breakpoints etc, so I decided to run from Visual Studio to IIS Express. But, when I start running my application I receive this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost,
>   Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 13:
>   Database.SetInitializer(new
>   TodoListServiceInitializer()); Line 14:
>   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); Line 15:
>   } Line 16:     } Line 17: }
>
> Source File:
>   C:\develop\spl_development\main\Docks\Docks_Sensor\Global.asax.cs
>   Line: 15
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/develop/Spl_Development/Main/Docks/Docks_Sensor/ LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\develop\Spl_Development\Main\Docks\Docks_Sensor\bin Calling
>   assembly : Docks.Sensor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\develop\Spl_Development\Main\Docks\Docks_Sensor\web.config LOG:
>   Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\ligthart\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/vs/25aafd2f/29cb2bd3/System.Web.Http.WebHost.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/25aafd2f/29cb2bd3/System.Web.Http.WebHost/System.Web.Http.WebHost.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/develop/Spl_Development/Main/Docks/Docks_Sensor/bin/System.Web.Http.WebHost.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build
>   Number ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   Docks.Sensor.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in
>   C:\develop\spl_development\main\Docks\Docks_Sensor\Global.asax.cs:15
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9966013
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +352
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947380 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

I've seen a lot of questions, but can't really seem to find an answer to this problem. I went looking if any of the required files or references were missing.. but no:

**References:**

[image]

**bin folder:**

[image]

**version:**

[image]

I have tried to remove the bin folder, everything.. I just can't seem to get it working. I hope there's a solution, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

remove System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll and add with old version 4.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried the solution provided by Hetal. But now it gives error in global.asax.cs in GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebAPICOnfig.Register) that it doesn't exist in the library.